# How I can add objectclass to an entry in ldap with ldif?

Tags: ldap

I have this schema:

```
attributetype ( 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
        NAME 'email2'
        DESC 'email2'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{256} )

objectclass ( 2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2  NAME 'myMember'
    DESC 'mymenber'
    SUP top STRUCTURAL
    MAY ( email2 ) )
```

And I have this object:

```
dn: o=myGroup,c=es
o: myGroup
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
```

I want to add the objectclass myMember to dn: o=myGroup,c=es. I have created ths ldif:

```
dn: o=myGroup,c=es
changetype: modify
add: objectclasses
objectclasses: myMember
```

But when I execute this, get an error:

```
>> ldapmodify -x -f modify.ldif -D 'cn=root,c=es' -W
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "o=myGroup,c=es"
ldapmodify: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectclasses: value #0 normalization failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EJP is right on the pure syntax point of view. But on the theorical point of view `mymenber` should be an AUXILIARY (Not STRUCTURAL) class to be added to object of others class.

```
objectclass ( 2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2  NAME 'myMember'
    DESC 'mymenber'
    SUP top AUXILIARY
    MAY ( email2 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Change 'objectclasses' to 'objectclass' throughout.

Comment: I've changed that and I get this other error:

ldapmodify: Object class violation (65)
 additional info: invalid structural object class chain (inetOrgPerson/iaaaMember)

Comment: @intropedro: not on that operation. There is no inetOrgPerson in your LDIF above. I don't understand you're adding a myMember class to a MyGroup object. Something seems very wrong with your object model.